Plain text parts of multipart MIME email notifications contain raw HTML
The HTML version of the notification looks great,

But the plain text part has raw HTML, particularly for the quote marks.

Just thought you would like to know.

Thanks for posting this; but quite frankly, I have given up on expecting useful plaintext email from corporations.

@tripleee I've almost entirely given up on expecting useful email.
